# How to compile and link header file in C++?

Tags: c++, c, compilation, linker, header-files

I am trying to work with the gpio_lib of cubietruck. Therefore I got the `gpio_lib.h` (see https://github.com/youyudehexie/node-cubieboard-gpio/blob/master/lib/gpio_lib.h) file located in my working directory:

```
> l
gpio_lib.h
test.cpp
```

In my `test.cpp` I have the following include:

```
#include "gpio_lib.h"
```

and some calls of the gpio_lib functions like `sunxi_gpio_init` and `sunxi_gpio_output` within the `main()` function.

However if I try to compile and link the send.cpp via

```
> g++ -o test -O3 -Wall test.cpp
```

I get

```
/tmp/ccULAi2f.o: In function `sequence_up()':
test.cpp:(.text+0x26a): undefined reference to `sunxi_gpio_output(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/tmp/ccULAi2f.o:test.cpp:(.text.startup+0xa2): more undefined references to `sunxi_gpio_output(unsigned int, unsigned int)' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also tried following calls getting the same error:

```
> g++ -o test -O3 -Wall gpio_lib.h test.cpp
> g++ -o test -O3 -Wall -I. -L. gpio_lib.h test.cpp
```

What is the correct way to compile and link the `test.cpp`?

Comment: you need to link the gpio library as well.

Comment: The question is: How?

Comment: add file gpio_lib.c to your project, at least :-}

Comment: That's the answer: I need the implemention too. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile and link the corresponding source file

```
g++ -o test test.cpp gpio_lib.c
```

Since the header is pure C, you'll need to add the language linkage yourself if you include it from C++:

```
extern "C" {
#include "gpio_lib.h"
}
```

Comment: @OP; This is the only correct answer at the time of this posting.

Comment: Right, that's the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot link with a header file. The error you are getting is linking error, i.e. function declaration was available in .h file, so it could compile, but definition of function is missing. You need to locate the correct library and link with that

Answer (score 2):

By inclusion of header `#include "gpio_lib.h"` you have brought probably some declarations of functions. Since the header is in C you should add a linkage specifier before `#include` definition

```
extern "C" {
    #include "gpio_lib.h"
}
```

to provide appropriate linkage. Then you have to **link** to the binaries that are the definitions (the body) of these functions as well or ask the gcc (g++ is gcc module) to do all the things for you:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp gpio_lib.c
```